# Datatables toggle column visibility delay/effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The tutorial on the [Datatables website](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html) is clear enough:

After I tell Datatables which column I'm talking about, I just put the toggle in:

```
column.visible( ! column.visible() );
```

or, in a more full on way, i could write:

```
if ( column.visible() === true ) {
    column.visible( false );
  } else {
    column.visible( true );
  }
```

Is there a way to put some sort of "timing" to this, maybe so that the column fades slowly, instead of just disappearing/reappearing?

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely not recommend fading a column. It's quite ugly and takes forever. The collapsing at the end will still happen.

Anyway, I have done this outside of `datatables` with simple jQuery. Basically, you keep your html the same, but you use regular jQuery to make stuff happen instead of datatables. Here's an example:

```
 $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
   var column = $(this).attr("data-column") - 1;

   $('.yourDataTable td:nth-child('+column+'), .yourDataTable th:nth-child('+column+')'  ).fadeOut();

   return false;
 }
```

Although, I do recommend against using `:nth-child`. If you are generating your datatable through means of a loop, I'd just add a `class="column_#"` to every column and use jQuery to grab that instead. (# being the number of the column)

**Edit: adding the settimeout example**

```
if ( column.visible() === true ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      column.visible( false );
    }, 500); //delays the function with 0.5 seconds
  } else {
    column.visible( true );
  }
```

Comment: This is really great - I appreciate the time you put into this response.  Whether I use fade or not - something to "slow it down" a tiny bit so the user can actually see the column in question coming and going might be helpful to my user base.  Just to know that it is possible is nice.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey there. If you want the user to have the time to see the column dissapear, you could always use a timeout, right? With that I mean simply delaying the action with a small amount of time. Should I write you up an example of this?